# Disable Hapi logs on test environment

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm using [Hapi](http://hapijs.com/) with [Good](https://github.com/hapijs/good) on a small project and want to disable some logs while testing (`process.env.NODE_ENV == 'test'`).

This is my `Good` configuration:

```
reporters: {
  console: [{
    module: 'good-console',
  }, 'stdout']
}
```

And this is the test output:

```
➜ npm test

  Index Route
    ✓ is ok
160622/214344.247, [response] http://paulodiovani-ideapad:3001: get / {} 200 (27ms)
```

How can I disable all logs, except `error`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post your `good` configuration? you probably want something like:

```
reporters: {
    console: [
      {
        module: 'good-squeeze',
        name: 'Squeeze',
        args: [{error: '*'}]
      },
      {
        module: 'good-console'
      },
      'stderr']
  }
```